# Why do some analog circuits use a FET with shorted drain and source?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, fet, body-diode

Why do some analog circuits use a FET with shorted drain and source? Depending of the type of FET, it may either act as a capacitor or a diode? It each case, why not just use a cap or a diode?
Below is one example.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That circuit uses a JFET as a very low leakage diode,  presumably, but there's no clear requirement for such a function as a similar diode is built into the CMOS gate, and 100K is not a particularly high resistance.

For example [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa058/sboa058.pdf) application note shows a diode-connected JFET used where fA matter.

[image]